# converting Wscript keyword vbs to powershell script

Tags: powershell

I got a code in vbs that i need to convert to powershell scrpit. WScript.Argument.item(n) in VBS script can be written as ?. how this can be written in powershell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell uses the automatic variable [$args](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-args.html)

```
# in vbs:
cscript script.vbs arg1 arg2
# returns arg1
WScript.Argument.item(0) 


# in powershell:
powershell script.ps1 arg1 arg2
# returns arg1
$args[0]
```

Comment: how does Wscript word works in powershell..is it valid in powershell?

Comment: '@Sanju R',. don't try and mix that in as it is not needed to do what you want. WScript is a cmd.exe executable (wscript.exe), not a command in PS. [You can pass any cmd.exe or executable in/to PS as long as you pass it (the command/executable) all it needs](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx), but that also means cmd.exe or the executable is in charge, not PS, though you can collect the output from those commands/executable in the PS stream.

Comment: @SanjuR `$args[n]` is the powershell equivalent to `wscript.argument.item(n)` in vbs. I only added wscript to the answer to show how to use it